# fit one-hot encoder on one column and apply to many

Tags: python, pandas, encoding

I have a dataframe with two categorical columns, containing the same set of strings, which I want to one-hot encode.
The set of strings that the columns can contain is determined and the one-hot encoding must be consistent between the two columns. Both columns contain all the possible values, even multiple times.

In the example below, I fit the encoder on a list containing the set of strings that the columns can contain. Then transform the columns of the dataframe.

Question 1: does this make sense?

Question 2: How to have distinct names for the columns returned by the one-hot encoding of the two columns? Now, I am able to put the columns in the datagrame, but they have names in common. It is a problem, right? How to avoid it?

```
#list of values
all_stuff = ['Boat','Bike']

#create dataframe
data = {'Stuff': ['Bike', 'Boat'], 'More Stuff': ['Boat', 'Bike']}
index = range(len(data['Stuff']))
columns = ['Stuff','More Stuff']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,  index=index, columns=columns)
df
```

[image]

```
#label encoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
label_encoder.fit(all_stuff)
df['Stuff'] = label_encoder.transform(df['Stuff'])
df

df['More Stuff'] = label_encoder.transform(df['More Stuff'])
df

#one-hot encoding on first column (fit and transform)
enc = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')
stuff_cols = enc.fit(df['Stuff'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

stuff_cols = enc.transform(df['Stuff'].values.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
stuff_cols

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(stuff_cols, columns=enc.get_feature_names())], axis=1)
df

#one hot enc on second column (ONLY tranform)
more_stuff_cols = enc.transform(df['More Stuff'].values.reshape(-1, 1)).toarray()
more_stuff_cols

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(more_stuff_cols, columns=enc.get_feature_names())], axis=1)
df

#the column nales are the same!!
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use pandas [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) function for that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Stuff': ['Bike', 'Boat'], 'More Stuff': ['Boat', 'Bike']})
pd.get_dummies(df)
```

Output:

```
   Stuff_Bike  Stuff_Boat  More Stuff_Bike  More Stuff_Boat
0           1           0                0                1
1           0           1                1                0
```